# Can all triple integrals have their order rearranged?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have an integral, and I can't seem to change its order, so I must ask:

Can all triple integrals have their order rearranged?($\mathrm{dx dy dz} \rightarrow \mathrm{dy dz dx})$ for example.

Are there integrals that require being broken apart to be changed in order?

Comment: yeah it can be rearranged....depends on the problem though... but you can rearrange it

Comment: @usukidoll I am asking if there is ever a case where you **cannot** interchange order of a perfectly described triple integral.

Comment: It is best to tell us what integral you are having problems with than asking a way too general question whose answer will not help you much (for what it's worth, the answer to your question is mostly given by [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) In all likelyhood, your problems rearranging the integral have nothing to do with this)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez The question is assigned, and I would rather completely avoid plagiarism than risk posting it. By your comment, I assume the answer is no?

You are likely right that it is merely my lack of skill that is prohibiting me from interchanging the order, but are there cases where the integral has to be broken apart to be set up in a different order or some other method that simplifies it?

Comment: strange... I have done triple integrals before.. sometimes I had to change the order otherwise I would be stuck...there are some easy problems where interchanging is unnecessary...

Comment: @usukidoll yes, I have done many triple integrals before, that is why it is a curious thing that I can't get this one to work.

Comment: well what is the triple integral problem?! If you're not specific, how can anyone help?

Comment: It seems odd to me that integrals aren't considered antisymmetric with regard to integration order when other measures of volume are (such as a determinant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that it has to be broken apart if the domain is concave.

I will show this on double integral for simplicity. Suppose you have to integrate $f(x,z)$ on the area bounded by $x$ axis, $x=3$, $x=-2$ and $z=x^2$.

It can be given as:
$$\int\limits_{-2}^{3}\int\limits_0^{x^2}f(x,z)\,\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}x$$

But, if you want to integrate $x$ first, you would have to split the domain:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{4}\int\limits_{-2}^{-\sqrt{z}}f(x,z)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}z+
\int\limits_{0}^{9}\int\limits^{3}_{\sqrt{z}}f(x,z)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}z$$

Comment: Thank you, I thought that was the case, and after reading your answer, I realised that breaking it up was sometimes necessary for single integration, and it would make sense to be needed for certain double and triple integrals(and likely n-tuple integrals).